# Etwas anschauen vs. ansehen = to look at?

Tags: verb, learning

Can *anschauen* and *ansehen* both be used to say that you are looking at something?  For example, "Ich *schaue* das Foto *an*" vs. "Ich *sehe* mir das Foto *an*"?  I think I have seen these verbs used interchangeably but I'm not a native speaker so I don't know if there's some difference in meaning I may have missed.

Are they exactly the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two verbs

> ansehen

and

> anschauen

are near-identical synonyms. They are, in fact, identical as to their *denotations*. People may disagree, however, as to the equivalence of their *connotations*. For example, when we hear or read *anschauen* we simultaneously hear or read a faint echo of the noun *Anschauung* in the back of our mind. There is *Weltanschauung* but not *Weltansehen*. Similarly, there is *Ansehen* (reputation) but not *Anschauen* (reputation).

Discussion of the question whether there can ever be wholly-equivalent synonyms can get very heated, so I'll end by saying that in my opinion, people sometimes do choose one of the verbs over the other, but based on a very subtle gut feeling and one that they usually would not be able to explicate if asked.

The **"too long, didn't read"**:

> Yes they are interchangeable and especially for you as a language learner this is something you need not worry about.

Comment: I'd like to add, that ansehen has one meaning that is not at all covered by "anschauen". Here is an example: "Man sieht ihr nicht an, wie alt sie ist"... "You can't tell her age by her looks" .... So ansehen+ non-reflexive dative = "tell by that persons look".

Comment: awesome!  that is a really helpful addition

Answer (score 6):

Yes the two verbs are synonyms which mean exactly the same. I can't think of an example in which one of the verbs would mean different things.

Perhaps the activity of watching a movie can be expressed better with *anschauen* instead of *ansehen*, but it's not a mistake to use *ansehen* either.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  Is the reflexive dative necessary with ansehen?  In other words, do I have to say "Ich sehe MIR das Foto an" or can I just say "Ich sehe das Foto an"?

Comment: Reflexive usage is better for things like pictures, photos, films etc. But it's not grammatically wrong to say: "Ich sehe das Foto an." (though it could mean something like *staring at a photo.*)

Comment: That’s the same for _anschauen_ and _ansehen_, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

`Anschauen` and `Ansehen` have an identical meaning. If you use `anschauen` or `ansehen` is mostly dependent on the region where you are.

For me `anschauen` is more directed to the object while `ansehen` is a bit more general.