# What is the difference between ‘anschauen’ and ‘ansehen’?

Tags: meaning, difference, verb-usage

Those two words *anschauen* and *ansehen* both mean *to look at*
and are synonyms in English but what's the difference? Are there cases where only one would be used?

Comment: There's not really a difference.

Comment: As a **verb**, there is hardly a difference (see answers). But the **noun** *Ansehen* (Reputation) has no *Anschauen* as equivalent. This is very likely related to the verb *ansehen* in the sentence with Einstein in the accepted answer (i.e. *angesehen sein als* = *have a reputation as* or *to be considered to be*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is almost no difference in meaning.
According to Duden Online, *anschauen* is used mostly in the southern part of Germany (Bavarian, Alemannic) and in Austria, Switzerland, or in literature, with the meaning of ansehen. *Ansehen* is more standard, and used in all types of media.
Same for *schauen*, which is used in those regions for *sehen* sometimes.

Only exception I can think of so far: 
**"Albert Einstein wird als der größte Physiker des 20. Jahrhunderts angesehen."** (= considered to be...). With this meaning, one can not use *anschauen* .

Please hold in mind that the adjectives *anschaulich* (concrete, clear) and *ansehnlich* (good-looking, considerable) hold very different meanings.

Also, if you search in this StackExchange, you can find related posts like this
[Etwas anschauen vs. ansehen = to look at?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6789/etwas-anschauen-vs-ansehen-to-look-at)

Comment: Yes, I would almost perceive that as a duplicate target.

Comment: Good observation about *anschaulich* vs. *ansehnlich*! Compare also *beschaulich* and *ersichtlich*.

Comment: And where in the south people use "anschauen" for "to watch (on TV)" in the north we would rather say "angucken".

Comment: "In all types of media" (in Bildern, Stummfilmen?) oder "for all types of media" wie Radio, Zeitung?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from regionally different usage, there's one difference between *ansehen* and *anschauen* that has not been mentioned yet.

*Ansehen* can also have the meaning of *to be visible* in a concrete or a figurative sense, thus *to be observable* (etw. ist wahrnehmbar / erkennbar). Examples:

> Sie ist weit über 70, aber man sieht ihr ihr Alter nicht an.
>
> Letztes Jahr ist seine Frau gestorben; man sieht ihm den Kummer an.
>
> Du lügst doch! Das sehe ich dir an der Nasenspitze an!

These sentences could never take *anschauen*, because *anschauen* always implies the act of intentionally looking at sth., whereas *ansehen* **can** imply an intention, but need not.